# MVC5 prevent modal window from popping up when returning from controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm having an issue where a modal window pops up in my browser after I return to the View from the controller.  Here's what the window says (in Chrome):

[image: Modal window pop up text]

It contains the html code from Index.cshtml page.

Here is the code in my controller:

```
public ActionResult Save(Events changedEvent,FormCollection actionValues)
        {
            string action_type = actionValues["!nativeeditor_status"];

            var eventText = actionValues["text"];
            var eventStart = actionValues["start_date"];
            var eventEnd = actionValues["end_date"];

            try
            {
                switch (action_type)
                {
                    case "inserted":
                        if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
                            db.Event.Add(changedEvent);                    
                        Send(eventText, eventStart, eventEnd);
                        break;

                    case "deleted":
                        //changedEvent = db.Event.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == source_id);
                        changedEvent = db.Event.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.text == eventText);
                        db.Event.Remove(changedEvent);
                        break;

                    default: // update
                        //changedEvent = db.Event.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.Id == source_id);
                        changedEvent = db.Event.SingleOrDefault(ev => ev.text == eventText);
                        UpdateModel(changedEvent);
                        break;
                }

                db.SaveChanges();

            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                action_type = "error";
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

Here is the code from my Index.cshtml page that handles saving to the database:

```
function init() { 
  var dp = new dataProcessor("/Home/Save");
        dp.init(scheduler);
        dp.setTransactionMode("POST", false);
    }
```

I'm still fairly new to MVC and have completed a few tutorials but I have never ran into this behavior before.  I was thinking I have to handle the callback from the controller but all my searching hasn't yielded anything so far.  I'm hoping someone from this fine community can point me in the right direction.

Thank you for taking the time to read!

Comment: search your code for `alert(`, looks as if someone is doing js debugging and forgot to remove it

Comment: I thing you are using Asynchronous POST(i.e ajax post method) from your    code , that is the reason response is not redirecting to Index page , instead it is showing alert(as @Pete commented) as string content from your index page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted on the dhtmlx forum and I was able to get a solution from one of their support staff.  I'm posting his answer in full below:

Hello,
here is what happens in your code
1) when you change something in scheduler (e.g. create/delete/modify event), scheduler sends a POST request to Home/Save, as defined in dataProcessor inside init() function()
2) dataProcessor sends post request and expects the server response to match a certain format of json or xml https://docs.dhtmlx.com/dataprocessor__ ... nsedetails
3) Your Save action outputs the html page instead of the expected response, this line:
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); 
4) client-side fails to parse it as a valid response and pops up a message.

In order to fix the issue, you need to return a valid response from the Save action, it can be done by replacing your current response - return
CODE: SELECT ALL

```
    RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); //with this:
      return Content(
        new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(
            new System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                {"action", action_type},
                {"tid", eventId}
            }
        )
    );

   // will send response like this {"action":"updated", "tid":"5"} - which is valid response
```

Please note "tid" - eventId part, if you insert event into db - you have to send new database event it back to the client. If it's any other operation - you can either return the same id as came from the client or omit "tid" field from the response.

This did the trick for me.  Thank you all for your comments and I hope my question helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to redirect from your C# controller if you are using an AJAX request (your dataProcessor is making an AJAX POST request internally).

You have two options:

1) Not to use your dataProcessor, and make a request to the server using the default C# MVC binding like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7856996/3638529. With this method, you will be able to return a RedirectToAction() and the user will be returned correctly, but this will probably change your infrastructure a lot.

2) Change your controller to return the url to redirect.
First change your save method to return something like this:

```
public ActionResult Save(Events changedEvent,FormCollection actionValues)
{
    ...
    return Json(new {success = true, url = Url.Action("Index", "Home")});
}
```

Then change your JavaScript method to make something like this when your AJAX request is complete:

```
function myAwesomeSuccessCallback(response) {
  if (response.success) {
     window.location = response.url;
  }
  else {
      //show error
  }
}
```